# How to use forEach loop correctly in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, foreach, angular2-services

I am new to Angular2 and here I am trying to loop through the array "mmEditorTypes" and checking the condition, if the condition is satisfied then I'll be executing the "open method".

But whenever i execute the below code, I am getting this error :

portalModeService: loading of portalMode threw exception:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined".

Could someone let me know how to fix this error?

**porta.service.ts :**

```
function isAppContained(viewState, appType){
      let angular:any;
      let isContained = false;
      angular.forEach(viewState.appViewStates, function (appViewState) {
        if (appViewState.signature.appType === appType) {
          isContained = true;
        }
      });
      return isContained;
    }
```

Comment: The question is answered but actually the error is actually because you have not initialised angular.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use **`angular.forEach`** with **`angular`** , its with angularjs.

use

```
for (let appViewState of viewState.appViewStates) {
   if (appViewState.signature.appType === appType) {
          isContained = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming `viewState.appViewStates` is an array, you can also use `Array.some`

Comment: Thank you @Sajeetharan , Now the error is resolved after replacing it with your code , But when i am executing this code , i am getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined error :  for(let editor of mmEditorTypes){
    // mmEditorTypes.forEach(function(editor)  {
      if (!isAppContained(viewState, editor.type)) {
        this.applicationLifeCycleService.open(editor.type, editor.payload);
      }
    } could you please let me know if i am doing anything wrong here ?.

Comment: i dont see anywhere you use length in the code yu provided

Answer (score 11):

As @Sajeetharan said you can't use angular.forEach in angular 2+

So you can use simple foreach in typescript like :

```
var someArray = [1, 2, 3];
someArray.forEach((item, index) => {
  console.log(item); // 1, 2, 3
  console.log(index); // 0, 1, 2
});
```